# How can I tell if a hidden stash or an enemy is within my honor range?

Tags: stronghold-kingdoms

There is a range within which discovering hidden stashes and attacking enemy camps will reward you honor points. This can easily be seen because the map around you is highlighted a light shade of red when you click on one of these stashes or camps. However, there are sometimes camps and stashes that fall on the border of this highlighted area.

Some of the times I have gotten honor but other times I didn't. I assume the ones in which I got honor was far enough within the border that it counts as being inside the honor range. But other times it looks like it might be far in enough but then I don't get honor. Is there a definitive way to tell if you will get honor for a specific hidden stash or enemy camp?

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the scouting screen when you choose how many to send it tells you in very tiny font how much honor you will get.